# JQuery Live Binding Multiple Radio Buttons or Radio Button Lists

Tags: jquery

I am trying to eliminate some redundancy, but I appear to be missing something that is probably obvious...

this does not work...

```
    $('input[type="radio"][name="rdoQuestionAnswer"][name="rdoQuestionAnswerYes"][name="rdoQuestionAnswerNo"]').live({    
    click: function (e) {
...
           }
        });
```

this does...

```
    $('input[type="radio"][name="rdoQuestionAnswer"]').live({    
    click: function (e) {
...
           }
        });
```

I don't want to have to create one of these for every radio button or radio button list...

comments, suggestions?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selectors, so that they are separated by a comma:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name="rdoQuestionAnswer"], input[type="radio"][name="rdoQuestionAnswerYes"], input[type="radio"][name="rdoQuestionAnswerNo"]')
```

**On a side note:** Are you sure you have to specify `type=radio`?

Comment: No it does not work without type=WhatEverTypeItIs (i tried with and without it and I am using the latest version of jquery) other than that this approach works... thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would add a class (with no accompanying styles) to each of those radio buttons and select that instead:

```
<input type="radio" class="selectme" name="rdoQuestionAnswer"/>
<input type="radio" class="selectme" name="rdoQuestionAnswerYes"/>
<input type="radio" class="selectme" name="rdoQuestionAnswerNo"/>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input.selectme').live('click', function() {...});
// or, to be modern about it:
$(document).on('click', 'input.selectme', function() {...});
```

Comment: This is definitely the best method. I would +1 but I've hit the daily limit :)

Comment: Started writing that I love the intro to the live() method then realized why I'd never heard of it, it's deprecated in 1.7+. That said the ".on()" is a perfect drop in replacement and I can exclude the selectors which are handled in the parent element, and stick to just the event type and handler. Love it! Thanks.

Comment: The O.P. may have been extremely intentional with his HTML, but, I would like to point out one thing: If you're dealing with mutually exclusive radio button/options, they should all have the same 'name' attribute to begin with, which negates the need to add a class. But, of course.. maybe you have a situation where you're dealing with radio buttons across various groups and this answer would indeed apply.